# Creating private reminders using iOS API?

Tags: ios, ios9, icloud, eventkit, reminders

Does `EKEventStore` allow the creation of "private" reminders, i.e. reminders that will be visible only to my app (the one that calls against the [EventKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) -- iOS events API) but not e.g. to Apple's default reminders app (for either iOS or OS X)?

Comment: If you only want your app to see it, why use EKEventStore? Seems like you'd be better storing your private reminder object some other way.

Comment: @JoGoFo I don't want to reinvent that particular wheel (e.g. the API's support for queries), but want my app's reminders to remain private, if possible. (They would just clutter the view in the default reminder apps. Otherwise the distinction is no big deal.)

Answer (score 3):

The `EKEventStore` provides access to the calendar/reminder resources that are available to the OS that are configured by the user.

It is not possible to configure a separate event store for private developer use.

Reminders can be made local so they are not synced in the cloud.

However, if the device has reminder lists that are synced to the cloud, then it is no longer possible to access the local reminders either by your app or the Reminders app.

This same behavior seems to apply to local Calendars where I answered a question about their availability at [Local EKCalendar saved with not errors, disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640657/local-ekcalendar-saved-with-not-errors-disappears/33641624#33641624).

The question at [Unable to create local EKCalendar (Reminders) if iCloud is set to not sync Reminders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430924/unable-to-create-local-ekcalendar-reminders-if-icloud-is-set-to-not-sync-remin) seems to support my conclusions and suggests this behavior has been present for at least a couple of years.